# How can I change programmatically a value of dx-select-box so valueChange is triggered?

Tags: angular, jasmine, devextreme-angular

I am using `Angular9`, `Jasmine` and `Devextreme`.

**My goal is to program a test that change the value of a `dx-select-box` so `valueChange` event is raised then assert the resulting effect.**

```
<dx-select-box
               [items]="filters"
               [value]="selectedFilterId"
               valueExpr="id"
               displayExpr="name"
              (valueChange)="filterChanged($event)">
</dx-select-box>
```

The issue that I am facing is `dx-select-box` is rendered as multiple `div`, so I do not see any `<select>` and `<option>` that I could manipulate.

The test look like:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();

// this line retrieve the initial value successfully
const firstSelectedFilterId = component.selectedFilterId;

// I tried a lot of unsuccessful code
// I did not find a way to trigger valueChange
...

// this retrieve the value after valueChange have been raised
const secondSelectedFilterId = component.selectedFilterId;

expect(firstSelectedFilterId).not.toEqual(secondSelectedFilterId);
```

Does someone have an idea how to raise a `valueChange` event from a `dx-select-box` in a Jasmine test?

Here a demo of dx-select-box: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxSelectBox/

Thank you for any hint!

**EDIT:** Just discovered:

```
const e1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(DxSelectBoxComponent));
const c1 = e1.componentInstance as DxSelectBoxComponent;
c1.valueChange.emit(newValue);
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Curiosity, how do I delete my question? Thanks!

Comment: Don't delete it because others might find it helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const e1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(DxSelectBoxComponent));
const c1 = e1.componentInstance as DxSelectBoxComponent;
c1.valueChange.emit(newValue);
fixture.detectChanges();
```